# Flip a FlipView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-rt

I have a FlipView (xaml) with ItemsSource binding on a list of periods (months). The periods are dynamically added to the list: when you go to the next period, the next period (of that next period) will be added to the list.

So if you have a list like this:

```
[October 2013, November 2013, December 2013, January 2014, February 2014, March 2014]
```

When you are on February 2014 and you press next, you'll go to March 2014 and April 2014 will be added to the list.

But I want to flip the FlipView, so that when you press (or swipe) back (to the left) it will go to the next index instead of the previous.

It's very difficult to explain, because English is not my native language. I hope you understand the problem...